# Citation style that sets Author (with et al if greater or equal 3), Date

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am making a beamer presentation and would like to know if there is a bibliography style that shows: 1st and 2nd author (and et al if there are more), and the year of publication.

Comment: Almost all bib styles that can generate authoryear-style citation call-outs provide the truncation mechanism you're interested in by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `maxcitenames` option for the standard Biblatex style. For instance:

```latex
\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
```

This should do it. There are many Mord options to adjust the outcome. E.g. `min/maxbibnames`, `min/maxcitenames` etc.